# Is the labiodental flap used only in the beginning of words?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa

In 2005, the IPA phonetical alphabet got extended by including the labiodental flap.

[The wikipedia-page shows a good overview.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labiodental_flap)

However, I am wondering if the labiodental flap is restricted to be only an initial phoneme?

Anyone got any example of words using the labiodental flap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not only word-initial though it does seem that it's almost always syllable-initial.

There are many examples, assembled at ['a cross linguistic lexicon of the labial flap'](http://journals.dartmouth.edu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Journals.woa/1/xmlpage/1/article/262?htmlOnce=yes) by Olson and Hajek.

Most of the O&H examples show it occurring in word-initial or intervocalic position, but there is at least one example of it in a consonant cluster (tho heterosyllabic), from Karang (Niger-Congo, Cameroon):

/pekⱱekⱱek/ ‘very high’

There is also a single example in the O&H dataset of a word-final occurrence, from Dii (Niger-Congo, Cameroon):

/ɓáⱱ/ 'sound of a horse galloping'